# Clicking link closes tooltip; how to prevent this

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the following code to toggle a tooltip

```
$('.call-out').toggle(
    function() { 
        $(this).find('.tip').addClass('tip-position').fadeIn("fast");
    },
    function() { 
        $(this).find('.tip').fadeOut("fast");
    }
);
```

In my .tip there is a list with some anchors, how do I prevent the tip from closing when clicking one of these links?

I tried using .not(); to exclude the anchors from the call-out but this is not working.

```
$('.call-out').not('a').toggle(
    function() { 
        $(this).find('.tip').addClass('tip-position').fadeIn("fast");
    },
    function() { 
        $(this).find('.tip').fadeOut("fast");
    }
);
```

HTML sample

```
<div class='call-out w PMPB12UN'>
   <div class='tip'>
      <img src="images/graph/DFN2020MD-6.png" />
      <p class="description">
         xx
      </p>
      <ul class="bullet-blue-list">
         <li><a href="/pip/PMPB12UN" target="_blank" title="xx">Product Information</a></li>
         <li><a href="#" target="_blank" title="#">xx</a></li>
         <li><a href="#" target="_blank" title="Buy online">Buy online</a></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
   <div class='product_image'>
      <img src="images/graph/DFN2020MD-6.png" />
   </div>
   <div class='label'>
      <div class='top'>
         <p class='title'>xx</p>
      </div>
      <div class='middle'>
      </div>
      <div class='bottom'>
         <p class='package'>DFN2020MD-6</p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is by adding `event.stoppropagation` on click of hyperlink. So that the click event on children `anchor` is not propagated to the parent which causes toggle.

```
$('.call-out a').click(function(e){
e.stopPropagation();
});
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/32std/)

Just note that this version of toggle is deprecated and not supported in later verisons of jquery.

See [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) Doc. For the lates ones where you will registed click events and perform toggle manually. It doesn't support itself as a virtual event and 2 callbacks anymore.